# Oracle to Vertica reqexp_replace - keep just numbers and alphas

Tags: regex, vertica

I am using the following expression in Oracle and it performs as expected returning only alpha numeric characters.  When I try to use it in Vertica I get null.  Any wisdom out there?

```
trim(upper(regexp_replace(PATIENT_CITY,'[^[:alpha:]^[:alnum:]'' '']', NULL))),
```

Comment: Try `''` instead of `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you setting the fourth parameter (position) to NULL?

The following statement works well:

SELECT regexp_replace('451 #$%!^ 657asdsg', '[^[:alpha:][:alnum:]'' '']')

Note the second caret ("^") should not be there (even for Oracle).